# How to localize settings in Wagtail

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, wagtail, django-i18n

I am trying to implement localization in Wagtail's settings. I know that Snippets can be localized by inheriting from the `TranslatableMixin` class. And it works perfectly.

However, when I try to localize settings by inheriting from this class in a model that also inherits from `BaseGenericSetting` to add the model to Wagtail's settings, it does not provide an interface to change the language in the admin panel so that I can create settings for different languages.

How can I add an interface for changing the language in the settings, similar to what we do with snippets?

For instance, I want to create instances of the below-mentioned model for three different languages (which are added in the LANGUAGES setting in base.py). This means there will be three instances of CompanySettings for three different languages.

```
@register_setting(icon="doc-full")
class CompanySettings(TranslatableMixin ,BaseGenericSetting):
    top_services = models.CharField(
        _("Top Services"), max_length=250, blank=True, null=True, help_text="add top services separated by comma")
    
    copyright_text = models.CharField(_("Copyright Text"), max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('top_services'),
        FieldPanel('copyright_text')
    ]
```

I have checked the `CompanySettings` model by querying its instance to verify whether the `locale` and `translation_key` fields are available or not, as these are provided by `TranslatableMixin`. However, even though they are available, it doesn't seem to work for Wagtail's settings.

Can somebody help me to solve this?
I just want to add settings for the `LANGUAGES` set in the `base.py`

Or suggest me a way to localize the rendered settings in the template.

Comment: As far as I know the settings models in Wagtail do not have native support for the same localization interface as pages or snippets, that being said I think you'd have to do work-around for this like localization in the template itself (I think this would be the easiest one if it's suitable for you)

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I found out that there is an active PR for it on their [github](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/9390#issuecomment-1441829309).
But, the author of the PR is [no longer picking it back up](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/9390#issuecomment-1441829309) - their work for their respective client was completed.
People just don't have that much free time if it's not in their interest.

I think a good portion of the work has been done though - you could easily implement further with your own custom templatetag implementation.
Yes, a bit tedious - but it'll *probably* work.

I'd still **love** for someone to work up an ***actual solution*** though. ;)